# urdfエラー Not transform from [ wheel ] to [base_link] RVizでStatus Error

Tags: xml

サンプルを元に、下記のようにcontinuousのjointをurdfに記載していますが
RVizで表示すると、 Not transform from [ left_wheel_link ] to [base_link] と接続が正しく認識されません。

他のサイトの車輪のサンプルを丸コピーしても同様に車輪のcontinuous部分がRVizで認識されないのですが、設定が足りないのでしょうか？

Jointsの「Joints in Alphabetic Order」「Links in Alphabetic Order」にはLink、Joint共に認識はされており、Positionなども入っていて、Show Axesを押せば、Axesは見えますが、車輪のvisualは表示されません。

なお、RVizでbase_linkは表示されています。

**参考にしたサイト**

[ROSで始めるロボティクス (3) - 差動二輪ロボットを準備する](http://bril-tech.blogspot.com/2016/10/ros3.html)
[ロボットモデリング講習会：URDFの作成方法 by gbiggs](https://gbiggs.github.io/rosjp_urdf_tutorial_text/mobile_robot_urdf.html)

**実行環境**
RViz 1.13.7 ( Melodic )
Ubuntu 18 LTS

**現状のソースコード**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<robot name="my_robo">
    <link name="base_link">
        <visual>
            <geometry>
                <box size="0.400 0.200 0.100"/>
            </geometry>
        </visual>
        <collision>
            <geometry>
                <box size="0.400 0.200 0.100"/>
            </geometry>
        </collision>
    </link>
    <link name="left_wheel_link">
        <visual>
            <geometry>
                <cylinder radius="0.1" length="0.05"/>
            </geometry>
            <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
            <material name="black"/>
        </visual>
    </link>

    <joint name="left_wheel_joint" type="continuous">
        <parent link="base_link"/>
        <child link="left_wheel_link"/>
        <origin rpy="-1.5707 0 0" xyz="-0.100 0.130 0"/>
        <axis xyz="0 0 1"/>
    </joint>
</robot>
```

Answer (score 1):

自分も同じ症状でした。調べてみたところ `joint_state_publisher` と `robot_state_publisher` が機能していないことが原因だったようです。以下のリンクが参考になると思います。

https://answers.ros.org/question/9365/no-transform-from-anything-to-base_link/